# Extract borg backup into remote server over SSH

Tags: arch-linux, borg-backup

I am using borg to take my system backup in Arch Linux.

I want to restore the backup in oracle virtual box and try to test. So I tried to do following thing.

The following things are done on oracle virtual-box

- Boot Arch ISO live boot in my machine virtualbox.
- Enable SSH in Virtual machine where live ISO is running.
- Virtual box running live CD, my ssh is listen on 22.
- I did a NAT port forwarding on oracle virtual box setting local port 8082 remote port
  22 for ssh.
- I was able to do ssh into Guest OS from Host OS.
- In the Oracle Virtual box I mounted /dev/sda1 on /mnt.

I was trying to extract my borg backup via ssh in remote machine (Arch live CD in oracle virtualbox). But nothing is happening. When search google able to get blogs taking backup over SSH. But what i want is restore backup over SSH. So that i don't want to install borg in my remote machine.

```
borg extract /mnt/mydata/borgbackup::20190506T21:03:56 |ssh root@127.0.0.1:/mnt -p 8082
```

Before I enter the borg password.

I get below message. If i enter the password it get extracted on the place where I am executing the command.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 127.0.0.1:/mnt: Name or service not known
```

I am not exactly getting, How to send these extracted files into /mnt folder in VM?

Comment: You are trying to pipe whatever `borg extract` outputs into SSH. This will not copy files to the destination host. Why not just use borg on the target, like it’s designed to?

Comment: Yes , but it is a fresh disk nothing is there. I just only have a live cd and ssh. Just only for this I need to have borg on remote server live cd. If I use --stdout in borg extract. I can write all file to stdout. But still I am not getting how to put all those file into specific folders in remote server.

Comment: I would like to do something similar, getting started with a fresh machine from a Borg backup would be very useful. @Vipin did you ever get this working?